# how to create an image slideshow with in div with multiple image

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an image slideshow in my page and I used the code below but it's not working.

HTML code:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

JS code:

```
var image_slide = new Array("01.jpg", "02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg");
var image_length = image_slide.length;
var image_current = 0;

function slide () {
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("slider").appendChild(image_current);
    };

    if (image_current >= image_length){
        image_current = 0;
    } else {
        document.slideshow.src = image_slide[image_current];
        image_current++;
    }
}

function auto () {
    setinterval(slide, 3000);
}
```

Also, is it correct to use file's path in array like `var image_slide = new Array("image/01.jpg","image/02.jpg");`?

Comment: Are you calling `slide()` from anywhere besides `auto()`?

Comment: You're appending a number to `#slider` not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes to your code. It is working perfectly .. previously you don't have the image tag and also initialization of the function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   var image_slide = new Array("01.jpg", "02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg");
   var image_length = image_slide.length;
   var image_current = -1;

   function slide () {
    if (image_current == image_length){
     image_current = 0;
    } else {
     image_current++;
    }
    document.slideshow.src = image_slide[image_current];
   }

   function auto () {
    setInterval(slide, 1000);
   }


   window.onload = function(){
    slide(); // To show the 1st image
    auto(); // Initialize the slider
   }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="slider">
   <img name="slideshow" />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I don't know the test case of window.onload but it's better to put your javascript after body or use jquery's onload to get rid of cross browser issues .. and also wrap everything into an object or function to keep it clean and to play safe with others